# Javascript count occurrences of Array in String

Tags: javascript

I need to count occurrences of an array in a string. I have problems with the special characters like `;/()`

```
var msg = "hello world :)"; 
var tce = [":)", ":(", ":/" ];
var countOcurrences = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tce.length; i++) {
  res = msg.match(/tce[i]/g);
  if (res != null) countOcurrences += res.length;
}
```

I think with regular expression, it may become more easy.

Comment: Do you mean you want to count how many times any item from your array appears in the string?

Comment: If the space before :) is mandatory means split(" ") will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you don't need any loops at all. Just construct one big regexp with alternatives (`|`) and match the string against it:

```
var tce = [":)", ":(", ":/"];

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/989121
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}

var re = RegExp(tce.map(RegExp.escape).join('|'), "g");

var msg = "hello :/ world :):)";
var countOcurrences = (msg.match(re) || "").length; // 3
```

Comment: Is nice code but I think it dont work with 0 ocurrences. ^^ ty for answer

Answer (score 2):

Forget about using regex and just use a simple `indexOf` to check for number of occurances. This function will help you:

```
function countMatches(str, find) {
    var count = 0;
    var index = str.indexOf(find);
    while (index != -1) {
        count++;
        index = str.indexOf(find, index + 1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

which you can use like this:

```
var msg = "hello world :)";
var tce = [":)", ":(", ":/"];
var countOcurrences = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < tce.length; i++) {
    countOcurrences += countMatches(msg, tce[i]);
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WY8n3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the array values to this:

`var tce = [":\)", ":\(", ":/" ];`

You need to escape `(` and `)` while using regex.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a regular expression for exact string matches.

You can use `indexOf`, use the 2nd parameter `offset` to find and count all occurrences.

```
var pos = msg.indexOf(str);
if (pos === -1) {
    // no match
}
var last_pos = pos;

pos = msg.indexOf(str, last_pos + 1);
if (pos !== -1) {
    counter += 1;
}
```

Do that in a loop, basically ^

Comment: `last_pos` needs to be incremented before before used in the subsequent `indexOf` calls, otherwise it will endlessly match the same index